# How to forward switchableControllerActions to another Controller action in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, extbase

My plugin configuration looks like this;

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin('Orbit.Navigator', 'mission', [
        \Orbit\Navigator\Controller\SpaceXController::class => 'cpt, cpr, shuttle',
        \Orbit\Navigator\Controller\Conf\FlightController::class => 'pressure,target,timer',
        \Orbit\Navigator\Controller\Conf\WeatherController::class => 'mav,hub',
]);
```

I have this setup,

```
10 = USER_INT
10 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = Navigator
    pluginName = mission
    vendorName = Orbit

    switchableControllerActions {
        SpaceX{
            1 = shuttle
        }
    }
}
```

The request lands in the `shuttleAction()` method in `SpaceXController`. After processing, How do I FORWARD it to `timerAction()` in `FlightController`?

Using;

```
$this->forward('timer', 'Flight', $this->request->getControllerExtensionName(), $this->request->getArguments());
```

acts like `$_POST` and results in;

```
(1/2) #1278450972 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\Exception\UnknownClassException
Class does not exist. Reflection failed.
```

Using;

```
$this->redirect('timer', 'Flight', $this->request->getControllerExtensionName(), $this->request->getArguments());
```

acts like `$_GET` (redirects to another page) and page throws an error complaining of "too many redirects".

Am able to forward to another action in the same Controller but how do I forward to another action in another Controller?

Comment: How does your plugin configuration look like? Is Flight -> timer an allowed controller-action pair?

Comment: Yes it's allowed. Am amending the question to include the configuration. Thanks to your question.

Comment: Your configuration puts your "FlightController in the "Conf" subdirectory. You probably have to forward/redirect to the controller name "Conf\Flight" to make it work. Though I'm not sure if that still applies that way in typo3 10 (that you seem to be using).

Comment: @Nitori Just tried that, also with a forward slash and tried moving `FlightController` to same Controller as `SpaceXController` without success. Any non-switchableControllerActions are forwarding to 'Flight' without a problem. Also noticed that if the `FlightController` is in a separate plugin in, `redirect()` seems to work but not `forward()`. Unfortunately for `redirect()`, the arguments are thrown into the address bar and changes page which is undesirable. Would like to forward without changing page, that is, using `forward()` or method or technique with similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that `switchableControllerActions` is being deprecated for the very reasons mentioned above. It override the original configuration of plugins at runtime. But am thankful I won't be relying on that setting. Although the deprecation notice mentions this, it further states that they're removing it for not adhering to it's paradigm for plugins. To quote from the deprecation notice thusly,

> `switchableControllerActions` have been marked as deprecated and will
> be removed in one of the next major versions of `TYPO3`, probably
> version `11.0` or `12.0`.
>
> `switchableControllerActions` are used to ***override*** the allowed set of
> controllers and actions via typoscript or plugin flexforms. While this
> is ***convenient*** for reusing the same plugin for a lot of different use
> cases, it’s also very ***problematic*** as it ***completely overrides*** the
> original configuration defined via
> `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin`.
>
> `switchableControllerActions` therefore ***have bad implications*** that
> rectify[sic] their removal.
>
> First of all, `switchableControllerActions` override the original
> configuration of plugins at runtime and possibly depending on
> conditions which contradicts the idea of
> `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin` being the
> authoritative way to define configuration.
>
> Using the same plugin as an entry point for many different
> functionalities contradicts the idea of a plugin serving one specific
> purpose. Switchable controller actions allow for creating one central
> plugin that takes care of everything.

Source: [Deprecation: #89463 - Deprecate switchableControllerActions](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.3/Deprecation-89463-SwitchableControllerActions.html)

I for one completely agree it's a good move.

There's a way around it that is made possible by TYPO3's capacity for multiple plugin definitions in the extension configuration file (ext_localconf.php) of a single extension. With that, one can define a dedicated plugin for any individual action needed in TypoScript or FlexForm.

Comment: So until  at least TYPO3 9 a solution is to define all controller-action pairs in switchableControllerActions.